# Bootstrap Dropdown ERB with select method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, erb

I am trying to create a dropdown with the look of the rest of my form on a page, but it is not coming out the way I want it to look.

I want it to look like this
[image: rails 3]

But it only looks like this 
[image: rails 4]

Here is the snippet where it is located

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :costcenter, "Cost Center" %>
    <%= select :request, :costcenter, options_for_select(Request.costcenters, {:selected => @request.costcenter.nil? ? 'Please Select' : @request.costcenter})%> 
  </div>
```

I have tried adding form-group and form-control to the class, appending to the end of the select function like so

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <%= f.label :costcenter, "Cost Center" %>
    <%= select :request, :costcenter, options_for_select(Request.costcenters, {:selected => @request.costcenter.nil? ? 'Please Select' : @request.costcenter}), {:class => 'form-control'}%> 
  </div>
```

but nothing seems to be working

Edit: The missing quote was just a typo: still not working

Comment: you seem to be missing a closing single quote ( ' ) after form-control.  Or is that a typo

Comment: it was just a typo, it has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `'` and not associate the value in proper manner

**Note:** There is no need of `ternary operator` condition, `rails select_tag` provide default functionality for the same.

Below `code` will fix your issue.

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
   <%= f.label :costcenter, "Cost Center" %>
   <%= select :request, :costcenter, options_for_select(Request.costcenters, @request.costcenter), {prompt: 'Please Select'},{ :class => 'form-control'}%>
 </div>
```